# Why does Haskell Stack keep downloading the same stuff?

Tags: haskell-stack, nixos

(In case it’s relevant, I use NixOS. Here’s [my NixOS config](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/nixos-experiments/blob/0f6155dfdf65e3b08d5439c5ffb3e17a8380cd64/configuration.nix).)

Each time I restart my computer, the first time I run stack ghci in a project, my system has had to download a ton of stuff. For instance, [my project montevideo](https://github.com/JeffreyBenjaminBrown/montevideo) just now started like this:

```
[jeff@jbb-dell:~/code/music/montevideo]$ stack ghci --ghci-options -Wall
these paths will be fetched (0.47 MiB download, 1.28 MiB unpacked):
  /nix/store/k21l8caw5y607f69vvysvj5p8wcpjmb0-glpk-4.65
  /nix/store/ykbr9ci7l3qmvj6l3i68z6a8r3j5pkbf-pcre-8.44-dev
  /nix/store/z5i9b7dxg5k5hmyspa5kdaj1c7j33zlq-pcre-8.44-bin
copying path '/nix/store/k21l8caw5y607f69vvysvj5p8wcpjmb0-glpk-4.65' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
copying path '/nix/store/z5i9b7dxg5k5hmyspa5kdaj1c7j33zlq-pcre-8.44-bin' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
copying path '/nix/store/ykbr9ci7l3qmvj6l3i68z6a8r3j5pkbf-pcre-8.44-dev' from 'https://cache.nixos.rg'...
Stack has not been tested with GHC versions above 8.6, and using 8.8.3, this may fail
Stack has not been tested with Cabal versions above 2.4, but version 3.0.1.0 was found, this may fail
Cabal file warning in/home/jeff/code/music/montevideo/montevideo-monome/montevideo-monome.cabal@0:0: A package using secti
on syntax must specify at least
'cabal-version: >= 1.2'.
Decimal             > configure
Decimal             > Configuring Decimal-0.5.1...
Decimal             > build
NumInstances        > configure
Decimal             > Preprocessing library for Decimal-0.5.1..
Decimal             > Building library for Decimal-0.5.1..
Decimal             > [1 of 1] Compiling Data.Decimal
NumInstances        > Configuring NumInstances-1.4...
NumInstances        > Warning: 'ghc-prof-options: -prof' is not necessary and will lead to problems
NumInstances        > when used on a library. Use the configure flag --enable-library-profiling
NumInstances        > and/or --enable-profiling.
NumInstances        > build
StateVar            > configure
NumInstances        > Preprocessing library for NumInstances-1.4..
NumInstances        > Building library for NumInstances-1.4..
NumInstances        > [1 of 5] Compiling Data.NumInstances.PreRequisites
NumInstances        > [2 of 5] Compiling Data.NumInstances.Function
...
```

It takes at least 5 minutes for most projects. Each project requires a separate download.

After that first download, I can start and stop GHCI in the project all I want, without having to re-download. But when I restart the machine, I need to download the libraries for each project separately all over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your machine on shutdown or restart automatically and nix-collect-garbage?

if you have a test machine, you can see the effect of this in

```
stack ghci --ghci-options -Wall
nix-collect-garbage
stack ghci --ghci-options -Wall
```

As the dependencies for stack ghci are being added to the GCROOT, so they are getting garbage collected. However garbage collection should only happen on if you run it, unless your system is configured to garbage-collect between reboots.

https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ssec-gc-roots

With nix-shell you can add dependencies it brings in to the gcroot so it doesn't reload them every time.

https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Storage_optimization (pinning section).

However i'm not sure how to do that with stack currently.

it does seem to mention in this in stack nix intergration documentation.

https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/nix_integration/

with the option.

```
add-gc-roots: true
```

which should

```
# false by default. Whether to add your nix dependencies as nix garbage
  # collection roots. This way, calling nix-collect-garbage will not remove
  # those packages from the nix store, saving you some time when running
  # stack build again with nix support activated.
  # This creates a `nix-gc-symlinks` directory in the project `.stack-work`.
  # To revert that, just delete this `nix-gc-symlinks` directory.
```

However I can't seem to get that working on my system.

However you project does compile fine :-).

Further research is that it's a known issue, where these gcroots are not being created as expected. :-(

https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4673

Comment: Adding `add-gc-roots: true` to `~/.stack/config.yaml` under `nix:` appears to have solved the problem! Thanks!